# Automatically limit playback volume only over headphones

Tags: windows-8.1, audio, speakers

There is a [closely related question](https://superuser.com/questions/498585/separate-volume-controls-for-headphone-and-speakers-in-windows-7) for windows 7, though 8 has a lot of changes, so I am hoping things may have changed.

My laptop speakers need to be at 100% and still it would be nice if the sound was louder. But I usually run my headphones at about 8%.

The problem is when I forget that I have the volume set for speakers and plug in headphones and start some music. **OUCH!!!** And it may damage the headphones too.

Is there a way to automatically cap playback volume over headphones?

Comment: My computer recognizes when I plug something into the headphone jack. Tell us a little about the PC. Sometimes there are hardware options. Also, are you plugging into the headphone jack on the computer or on the speakers?

Answer (score 0):

If they both use the same mini-phone connection, there's no way for the PC to distinguish between speaker and headphones. However, there are some easy solutions:

1. Use a headphone splitter, and add two small potentiometers (or a ganged pot) of about 200 ohms on the side for the headphones (two outer leads to the PC-side, one outer and center to phones). You can leave the phones attached all the time.
2. Use a [headphone volume control](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00001P4XH) or make your own with a couple of pots (or just series resistors, experimentally determined) as above.
3. Put silicon diodes in parallel back-to-back across the headphone leads. Si diodes don't conduct until ~0.6 V, at which point they limit the voltage across the phones. Use two in series on either side for ~1.2 V limit.

Comment: By laptop speakers, I meant the ones built into the laptop. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: In that case, the second and third suggestions still apply, but there *should* also be separate volume control settings for headphone and for internal speakers.in the Windows Control Panel or an add-on CPL (e.g. *SmartAudio*) that was installed by the laptop maker. You can also install a third-party utility, such as Volume2; see http://alternativeto.net/tag/volume-control/?platform=windows .